# Python file transfer completes only after Control-C

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, file-transfer

I am trying the multithreaded python program to connect to server by multiple clients at the same time. The program runs successfully but the image I am trying to send has incomplete data until I terminate the program using Control C. After Control-C, the file reloads and complete image is visible.
I am posting my code here :
Server.py

```
from socket import *
import thread

def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr):
    print "Accepted connection from: ", clientaddr

    while 1:
        data = clientsocket.recv(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            print "The following data was received - ",data
            print "Opening file - ",data
            fp = open(data,'r')
            strng = "hi"
            while strng:
                strng = fp.read(8192)
                clientsocket.send (strng)


    clientsocket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    host = 'localhost'
    port = 55574
    buf = 8192

    addr = (host, port)

    serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    serversocket.bind(addr)

    serversocket.listen(5)

    while 1:
        print "Server is listening for connections\n"

        clientsocket, clientaddr = serversocket.accept()
        thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsocket, clientaddr))
    serversocket.close()
```

Client.py :

```
from socket import *
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':

    host = 'localhost'
    port = 55574
    buf = 8192

    addr = (host, port)

    clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    clientsocket.connect(addr)

    while 1:
        fname = raw_input("Enter the file name that u want>> ")
        if not fname:
            break
        else:
            clientsocket.send(fname)
            print "\nThe file will be saved and opened- "
            fname = '/home/coep/Downloads/'+fname
            nf = open(fname,"a")
            strng = "hi"
            while strng:
                strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
                nf.write(strng)

            nf.close()
            fname = 'viewnior '+ fname
            print fname
            os.system(fname)
```

Comment: You should use `sendall()` instead of `send()`, if you don't want to check carefully the return value of `send()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
            while strng:
                strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
                nf.write(strng)
```

To:

```
            while True:
                strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
                if not strng:
                    break
                nf.write(strng)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's so many things wrong with that code:

1) Both server and client. Sending and receiveing files might be tricky. Have a look at this:

```
while strng:
    strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
    nf.write(strng)
```

An infinite loop. You have to add

```
while strng:
    strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
    if not strng:
        break
    nf.write(strng)
```

to the server. But **the client won't know when you've stopped transmiting the file** (and that's the source of your problem). Therefore you either have to send some `STOP` value (which might be tricky if the file contains such string) or send the size of file before sending the content (so the client will know how much data it should read). The second solution is preferred (for example that's how HTTP works).

2) Don't use `thread` module. It's low level and it is easy to make mistakes. Use `threading`.

3) The server. You open a file with `fp = open(data,'r')` but you don't close it anywhere. Instead use `with`:

```
with open(data, 'r') as fp:
    # the code that uses fp goes here
```

It will automatically close the file once it leaves the block.

4) Don't use `os.system` unless you absolutely have to. I understand that this is just for debugging but a good advice anyway.

5) Use `socket.sendall` instead of `socket.send` if you don't want to bother with tricky internals of system's `send` call. Might not matter in your case though.